# Multithreading task to process files in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task, async-await

I've been reading a lot about threading but can't figure out how to find a solution to my issue.
First let me introduce the problem. I have files which need to be processed. The hostname and filepath are located in two arrays.

[image]

Now I want to setup several threads to process the files. The number of threads to create is based on three factors:
A) The maximum thread count **cannot** exceed the number of unique hostnames in all scenarios.
B) Files with the same hostname **MUST** be processed sequentially. I.E We cannot process **host1**_file1 and **host1**_file2 at the same time. (Data integrity will be put at risk and this is beyond my control.
C) The user may throttle the number of threads available for processing. The number of threads is still limited by condition A from above. This is purely due to the fact that if we had an large number of hosts let's say 50.. we might not want 50 threads processing at the same time.

In the example above a maximum of 6 threads can be created.

The optimal processing routine is shown below.

[image: Optimal processing routineRoutine]

```
public class file_prep_obj
{
    public string[] file_paths;
    public string[] hostname;
    public Dictionary<string, int> my_dictionary;

    public void get_files()
    {
        hostname = new string[]{ "host1", "host1", "host1", "host2", "host2", "host3", "host4","host4","host5","host6" };
        file_paths=new string[]{"C:\\host1_file1","C:\\host1_file2","C:\\host1_file3","C:\\host2_file1","C:\\host2_file2","C:\\host2_file2",
                                "C:\\host3_file1","C:\\host4_file1","C:\\host4_file2","C:\\host5_file1","C:\\host6_file1"};
        //The dictionary provides a count on the number of files that need to be processed for a particular host.
        my_dictionary = hostname.GroupBy(x => x)
                        .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                        g => g.Count());
    }
}

//This class contains a list of file_paths associated with the same host.
//The group_file_host_name will be the same for a host.
class host_file_thread
{
    public string[] group_file_paths;
    public string[] group_file_host_name;

    public void process_file(string file_path_in)
    {
        var time_delay_random=new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("Started processing File: " + file_path_in);
        Task.Delay(time_delay_random.Next(3000)+1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Completed processing File: " + file_path_in);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        file_prep_obj my_files=new file_prep_obj();
        my_files.get_files();
        //Create our host objects... my_files.my_dictionary.Count represents the max number of threads
        host_file_thread[] host_thread=new host_file_thread[my_files.my_dictionary.Count];

        int key_pair_count=0;
        int file_path_position=0;
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in my_files.my_dictionary)
        {
            host_thread[key_pair_count] = new host_file_thread();   //Initialise the host_file_thread object. Because we have an array of a customised object
            host_thread[key_pair_count].group_file_paths=new string[pair.Value];        //Initialise the group_file_paths
            host_thread[key_pair_count].group_file_host_name=new string[pair.Value];    //Initialise the group_file_host_name


            for(int j=0;j<pair.Value;j++)
            {
                host_thread[key_pair_count].group_file_host_name[j]=pair.Key.ToString();                        //Group the hosts
                host_thread[key_pair_count].group_file_paths[j]=my_files.file_paths[file_path_position];        //Group the file_paths
                file_path_position++;
            }
            key_pair_count++;
        }//Close foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> pair in my_files.my_dictionary)

        //TODO PROCESS FILES USING host_thread objects. 
    }//Close static void Main(string[] args)
}//Close Class Program
```

I guess what I'm after is a guide on how to code the threaded processing routines that are in accordance with the specs above.

Comment: +1 for the nice visualization of your question.

Comment: @Complexity Thanks.. A picture does say 1000 words.

Comment: Something that comes to mind. Is your array always built up like this? I mean: "Does the item at index 0 in array A always corresponds with the item at index 0 in array B and this for all the indexes"?

Comment: Also, in your question you do have 2 times the same filename for host 4, while in your picture "optimal processing" this has been gone. I guess it's a typo?

Comment: The two arrays will always be linked yes..I have corrected the typo. Cheers.

Comment: I see you put a lot of effort in your question. But I don't see a question... What's the specific problem you are facing? What didn't work, what have you tried? The title isn't descriptive either.

Comment: My question is about effective threading/tasking methods I can use run the process_file job using the host_thread object that also meet the 3 requirements. I'm no expert in multi-threading so am open to solutions. Thx for reading.

Comment: @PeterH: Do you really need multiple threads? You won't get a benefit with multiple threads when dealing with disk-bound IO unless your hardware is set up for that. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/902455/324260

Comment: The processing really is intense.. I'm dealing with literally hundreds of files on a daily basis. They range from a couple of MB to hundreds of MB. The processing takes many hours to complete. Data is parsed and goes into a DB... Some Disk IO limitations may be uncovered in the future if we get this right :-) ... Currently only using 1 thread in the current code I have implemented and this needs to change.

Comment: Get yourself familiar with TPL Dataflow: http://t.co/9JM7k6tLAS, it's a perfect high-level tool for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Stephen Toub's [ForEachAsync](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/05/10278165.aspx) extension method to process the files. It allows you to specify how many concurrent threads you want to use, and it is non-blocking so it frees up your main thread to do other processing. Here is the method from the article:

```
public static Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int dop, Func<T, Task> body)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(
        from partition in Partitioner.Create(source).GetPartitions(dop)
        select Task.Run(async delegate
        {
            using (partition)
                while (partition.MoveNext())
                    await body(partition.Current);
        }));
}
```

In order to use it I refactored your code slightly. I changed the dictionary to be of type `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` and it basically holds the host as the key and then all the paths as the values. I assumed the file path will contain the host name in it.

```
   my_dictionary = (from h in hostname
                    from f in file_paths
                    where f.Contains(h)
                    select new { Hostname = h, File = f }).GroupBy(x => x.Hostname)
                    .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(s => s.File).Distinct().ToList());
```

I also changed your `process_file` method to be `async` as you were using `Task.Delay` inside it, which you need to `await` otherwise it doesn't do anything.

```
public static async Task process_file(string file_path_in)
{
    var time_delay_random = new Random();
    Console.WriteLine("Started:{0} ThreadId:{1}", file_path_in, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    await Task.Delay(time_delay_random.Next(3000) + 1000);
    Console.WriteLine("Completed:{0} ThreadId:{1}", file_path_in, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

To use the code, you get the maximum number of threads you want to use and pass that to `my_files.my_dictionary.ForEachAsync`. You also supply an asynchronous delegate which processes each of the files for a particular host and sequentially awaits each one to be processed.

```
public static async Task MainAsync()
{
    var my_files = new file_prep_obj();
    my_files.get_files();

    const int userSuppliedMaxThread = 5;
    var maxThreads = Math.Min(userSuppliedMaxThread, my_files.my_dictionary.Values.Count());
    Console.WriteLine("MaxThreads = " + maxThreads);

    foreach (var pair in my_files.my_dictionary)
    {
        foreach (var path in pair.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Key= {0}, Value={1}", pair.Key, path);   
        }            
    }

    await my_files.my_dictionary.ForEachAsync(maxThreads, async (pair) =>
    {
        foreach (var path in pair.Value)
        {
            // serially process each path for a particular host.
            await process_file(path);
        }
    });

}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
    Console.ReadKey();

}//Close static void Main(string[] args)
```

**Ouput**

```
MaxThreads = 5
Key= host1, Value=C:\host1_file1
Key= host1, Value=C:\host1_file2
Key= host1, Value=C:\host1_file3
Key= host2, Value=C:\host2_file1
Key= host2, Value=C:\host2_file2
Key= host3, Value=C:\host3_file1
Key= host4, Value=C:\host4_file1
Key= host4, Value=C:\host4_file2
Key= host5, Value=C:\host5_file1
Key= host6, Value=C:\host6_file1
Started:C:\host1_file1 ThreadId:10
Started:C:\host2_file1 ThreadId:12
Started:C:\host3_file1 ThreadId:13
Started:C:\host4_file1 ThreadId:11
Started:C:\host5_file1 ThreadId:10
Completed:C:\host1_file1 ThreadId:13
Completed:C:\host2_file1 ThreadId:12
Started:C:\host1_file2 ThreadId:13
Started:C:\host2_file2 ThreadId:12
Completed:C:\host2_file2 ThreadId:11
Completed:C:\host1_file2 ThreadId:13
Started:C:\host6_file1 ThreadId:11
Started:C:\host1_file3 ThreadId:13
Completed:C:\host5_file1 ThreadId:11
Completed:C:\host4_file1 ThreadId:12
Completed:C:\host3_file1 ThreadId:13
Started:C:\host4_file2 ThreadId:12
Completed:C:\host1_file3 ThreadId:11
Completed:C:\host6_file1 ThreadId:13
Completed:C:\host4_file2 ThreadId:12
```

Comment: @Ned_Stoyanov Looks like a very Elegant and Clean solution. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I would start by organizing your data structure a bit better. Having two separate arrays not only increases data duplication, but also creates implicit coupling which may not be obvious to the person looking at your code.

A class which would hold information about a single task might look something like:

```
public class TaskInfo
{
    private readonly string _hostName;
    public string HostName
    {
        get { return _hostName; }
    }

    private readonly ReadOnlyCollection<string> _files;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<string> Files
    {
        get { return _files; }
    }

    public TaskInfo(string host, IEnumerable<string> files)
    {
        _hostName = host;
        _files = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(files.ToList());
    }
}
```

Creating a list of tasks is now much more straightforward:

```
var list = new List<TaskInfo>()
{
    new TaskInfo(
        host: "host1",
        files: new[] { @"c:\host1\file1.txt", @"c:\host1\file2.txt" }),

    new TaskInfo(
        host: "host2",
        files: new[] { @"c:\host2\file1.txt", @"c:\host2\file2.txt" })

    /* ... */
};
```

And now that you have your tasks ready, you can simply use various classes from the `System.Threading.Tasks` namespace to invoke them in parallel. If you really want to limit the number of concurrent tasks, you can simply use the [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) property:

```
Parallel.ForEach(
    list, 
    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 },
    taskInfo => Process(taskInfo)
);
```

If you wanted to create your own pool of threads, you could have also achieved a similar thing using a `ConcurrentQueue` with multiple consumer threads, possibly waiting on a list of `WaitHandle`s to know when they're done.

Comment: Will give this a try. The MaxDegreeOfParallelism option will make controlling the threads hopefully easier. Cheers for the approach.

Answer (score 1):

I was playing around with your problem and came up with the folllowing approach. It might not be the best, but I believe it suits your needs.

Before we begin, I'm a big fan of extension methods, so here is one:

```
public static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static void Each<T>(this IEnumerable<T> ie, Action<T, int> action)
    {
        var i = 0;
        foreach (var e in ie) action(e, i++);
    }
}
```

What this does is looping over a collection (foreach) but keeping the item and the index. You'll see why this is needed later.

Then we have the variables.

```
public static string[] group_file_paths =
{
    "host1", "host1", "host1", "host2", "host2", "host3", "host4", "host4",
    "host5", "host6"
};

public static string[] group_file_host_name =
{
    @"c:\\host1_file1", @"c:\\host1_file2", @"c:\\host1_file3", @"c:\\host2_file1", @"c:\\host2_file2", @"c:\\host3_file1",
    @"c:\\host4_file1", @"c:\\host4_file2", @"c:\\host5_file1", @"c:\\host5_file2", @"c:\\host6_file1" 
};
```

Then the main code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> filesToProcess = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

    // Loop over the 2 arrays and creates a directory that contains the host as the key, and then all the filenames.
    group_file_paths.Each((host, hostIndex) =>
    {
        if (filesToProcess.ContainsKey(host))       
        { filesToProcess[host].Add(group_file_host_name[hostIndex]); }
        else
        {
            filesToProcess.Add(host, new List<string>());
            filesToProcess[host].Add(group_file_host_name[hostIndex]);
        }
    });

    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (var kvp in filesToProcess)
    {
        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            foreach (var file in kvp.Value)
            {
                process_file(kvp.Key, file);
            }
        }));
    }

    var handleTaskCompletionTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    handleTaskCompletionTask.Wait();
}
```

Some explanation might be needed here:

So I'm creating a dictionary that will contains your hosts as the key and as the value a list of files that needs to be processed.

Your dictionary will look like:

- Host1

  - file 1
  - file 2
- Host 2

  - file 1
- Host 3

  - File 1
  - File 2
  - File 3

After that I'm creating a collection of tasks that will be executed by using TPL.
I execute all the tasks right now and I'm waiting for all the tasks to finish.

Your process method seems as follow, just for testing purposes:

```
    public static void process_file(string host, string file)
    {
        var time_delay_random = new Random();
        Console.WriteLine("Host '{0}' - Started processing the file {1}.", host, file);
        Thread.Sleep(time_delay_random.Next(3000) + 1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Host '{0}' - Completed processing the file {1}.", host, file);
        Console.WriteLine("");
    }
```

This post does not include a way to set the threads yourself but it can be easily achieved by using a completion handler on the tasks. Than when any task complete, you can loop again over your collection and start a new task that hasn't been finished yet.

So, I hope it helps.

Comment: Thankyou!! Some nice tips...The dictionary fix will be very helpful as well...Didn't really like the way I implemented mine.. Yours is much nicer.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It's not optimal yet. As other users suggest, you should create a seperate class for holding a task. But I kept going with your arrays because of your question it's not clear if you were able to change this. You might fetch the data from some other place. However, even if you fetch it from another place, you can still transform it into classes and work with those. If you need help on that one, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

I think [`ThreadPool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the perfect solution for you. It will handle the threads by itself and queue their work. Moreover, you can set the maximum threads limit and it will still queue your work even if you have more than the maximum number of threads.

```
ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads([YourMaxThreads],[YourMaxThreads]);

foreach (var t in host_thread)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(Foo, t);
}
```

```
private static void Foo(object thread)
{
    foreach (var file in (thread as host_file_thread).group_file_paths)
    {
        (thread as host_file_thread).process_file(file);
    }
}
```

Although I would suggest you change your data structure and keep the `process_file` method from it

Comment: Nice proposal. Thankyou for taking the time to read and answer. What would you suggest I do with the process_file method?

Comment: @PeterH You are creating a class which basically just holds your files array. This is just memory overhead. Instead I'd suggest to have a `Dictionary<string,string[]>` which the key is going to be your host and the value is the corresponding files for that host. Afterwards just make the method `process_file` static.

Comment: How do you prevent the main thread from closing before the processing has been completed? I'm finding that main is exiting and not waiting on the other threads.

Comment: @PeterH I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/540143/1459484) can help you out