# TaskScheduler for parallel Asyc Tasks

Tags: c#

Feel free to ask for more context.

I have a requirement where a lot of tasks come and they can get in large number. So I want to throttle the queuing of tasks and want to control the concurrency also. Till now I have found that I can created a Custom TaskScheduler that limits the concurrency (I read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx) and also when tasks queued becomes more than a maximum limit I block the task scheduling in TaskFactory.StartNew method. Here are my questions:

1. Is there a better advice to do this in a simple way please feel free to suggest.
2. Also, in the implementation of LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler I see that the implementation is using a ThreadPool underneath. Can I use something other than threadpool to schedule tasks? Doesn't extending the TaskScheduler gives the behavior of executing the in a threadpool and we jsut need to tell how to queue and dequeue tasks. Right?
3. If we look at the Default TaskScheduler it uses the ThreadPool underneath as well. There are two things MaximumConcurrencyLevel and the thread count in ThreadPool. So if we set the MaximumConcurrencyLevel to integer. Then the concurrency level will depend on the threadpool count. How are the two related in default implementation. If the concurrency eventually depends on the threadpool count then what is the point of MaximumConcurrencyLevel used for in the framework?

Comment: Can you format your question?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Sorry my bad. Done it.

Comment: Not an answer to your question(s) but you may want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18771524/limit-the-number-of-tasks-in-task-factory-start-by-second)

Comment: You can control the maximum concurrency level with `ForEachAsync` extension method. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/24628962/1239433 answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered any of the specialized task schedulers from parallel extensions extras?

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the link. I would still want to get answer to all the three questions that I have.