# Execute in parallel with limited concurency

Tags: c#, multithreading, silverlight, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I would like to execute async operations in parallel, in Silverlight 5, with limited concurency.

My code is like :

```
    public async void btn_click(object s, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await DoAllWork();
    }

    private async Task DoAllWork()
    {
        //Get work to do
        int[] wrk = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

        //Start the tasks
        Task[] tasks = new Task[wrk.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < wrk.Length; i++)
        {
            int item = wrk[i];
            tasks[i] = WorkSingleItem(item);
        }
        await TaskEx.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private async Task WorkSingleItem(int item)
    {
        //a very long operation
        var response = await Request(item);
        await Handle(response);
    }
```

I have found this article : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx

How can I await my work method, that start all my long operations with the "limited concurrency scheduler", and with each item work not relying on synchronization context to avoid code executed in UI thread...

Comment: The task WhenAny method would be a good fit. You can use it to start a collection of tasks and it reports when one of them completes. When that happens you can add another task. Wrapped in a while 'has more tasks' loop you should get the desired behaviour. I'm not at a workstation to put a sample together so will put one up later.

Comment: Your question is vague, you need to explain a bit more what you're trying to do. Is this work IO bound or CPU bound, what does "limited concurreny" mean to you?

Comment: "limited concurency" = "number of parallel tasks active". If I have 20 items, I don't want to work on all 20 at once, but only 4 at a time, to avoid a ddos on my server.
And I don't want the item handling code to use the synchronization context to avoid code execution in the UI thread.

Comment: Are these all cpu bound operations?

Comment: You can do this with `ForEachAsync` from Stephen Toub, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/24628962/1239433

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your long operations deal with I/O asynchronously, and the purpose of the limited concurrency is to avoid a DDoS, then a `TaskScheduler` is an incorrect solution. This is because a `TaskScheduler` only controls active tasks (running or blocked); when a task yields back to its scheduler via `await`, it's no longer considered "active". So, a `TaskScheduler` can't be used to prevent a DDoS if your I/O is asynchronous.

The correct solution is to use something like an [`async`-compatible semaphore](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/02/12/10266983.aspx):

```
public async void btn_click(object s, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  await Task.Run(() => DoAllWork());
}

private async Task DoAllWork()
{
  int[] wrk = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
  var semaphore = new AsyncSemaphore(4);

  var tasks = wrk.Select(x => WorkSingleItem(x, semaphore));

  await TaskEx.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private async Task WorkSingleItem(int item, AsyncSemaphore semaphore)
{
  await semaphore.WaitAsync();
  try
  {
    var response = await Request(item);
    await Handle(response);
  }
  finally
  {
    semaphore.Release();
  }
}
```

Comment: I find that this pattern comes up enough that it's actually worth abstracting this logic out into it's own class (as seen in my answer) to allow you to both separate out the concerns and therefore reduce the complexity of each method, and also allows you to use it on operations that you can't control the source of.

Comment: I like that abstraction. In my own experience, once someone needs a limited concurrency queue, they're usually better off just switching to TPL Dataflow. Not for a simple one-off problem like this, of course, but I find that if this *part* of the code needs a queue, then the nearby parts of the code would benefit from a pipeline.

Comment: Sure.  Probably the one exceptional case that such a queue can handle is that TPL data flow is really designed for rate limiting a single operation, whereas such a queue could be passed around and have a handful of separate operations be rate limited together, without going to the global route of using a `SynchronizationContext` that rate limits parallelization for *everything* (which is also a useful tool).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a type of queue that will only allow a certain number of the given tasks to be executing at one time:

```
public class FixedParallelismQueue
{
    private SemaphoreSlim semaphore;
    public FixedParallelismQueue(int maxDegreesOfParallelism)
    {
        semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxDegreesOfParallelism,
            maxDegreesOfParallelism);
    }

    public async Task<T> Enqueue<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskGenerator)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            return await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
    public async Task Enqueue(Func<Task> taskGenerator)
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            await taskGenerator();
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

This would let you write:

```
private Task DoAllWork()
{
    int[] work = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

    var queue = new FixedParallelismQueue(maxDegreesOfParallelism);
    var tasks = work.Select(n => queue.Enqueue(() => WorkSingleItem(n));
    return TaskEx.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```