# Managing threads efficiently in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have an application in which the user will choose to do a number of tasks along with the maximum number of threads. Each task should run on a separate thread. Here is what I am looking for:

If the user specified "n less than t" where n is the maximum number of threads and t is the number of tasks. The program should run "n" threads and after they finish, the program should be notified by some way and repeat the loop untill all tasks are done.

My Question is:
How to know that all running threads has finished their job so that I can repeat the loop.

Comment: Just wondering, but is there any reason why you can't dump all your tasks in the ThreadPool? Seems the ThreadPool is tuned *exactly* for this purpose, and takes the burden off the client who has to guess the optimal number of threads to execute.

Comment: If you can provide a detailed description on how to do that, Please add an answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [be notified when all background threadpool threads are finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/358721/be-notified-when-all-background-threadpool-threads-are-finished)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recommend using the [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5htx827.aspx) for your task. Its algorithm will generally be more efficient than something you can roll by hand.

Now the fun part is getting notified when all of your threads complete. Unless you have really specific needs which make this solution unsuitable, it should be easy enough to implement with the [CountdownEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.countdownevent.aspx) class, which is a special kind of waithandle that waits until its been signaled `n` times. Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace CSharpSandbox
{
    class Program
    {
        static void SomeTask(int sleepInterval, CountdownEvent countDown)
        {
            try
            {
                // pretend this did something more profound
                Thread.Sleep(sleepInterval);
            }
            finally
            {
                // need to signal in a finally block, otherwise an exception may occur and prevent
                // this from being signaled
                countDown.Signal();
            }
        }

        static CountdownEvent StartTasks(int count)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();

            CountdownEvent countDown = new CountdownEvent(count);

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => SomeTask(rnd.Next(100), countDown));
            }

            return countDown;
        }

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting. . .");
            var stopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            using(CountdownEvent countdownEvent = StartTasks(100))
            {
                countdownEvent.Wait();
                // waits until the countdownEvent is signalled 100 times
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Done! Elapsed time: {0} milliseconds", stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I knew you'd answer the question the way I wanted. Thanks Juliet.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use a [Thread Pool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for this. You (can) specify the number of threads in the pool, and give it tasks to do. When a thread in the pool is idle, it automatically looks for another task to carry out.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this without the thread pool, you can use `Thread.Join` to wait for the threads to complete.  That is:

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(...);
Thread t2 = new Thread(...);
t1.Start();
t2.Start();

// Wait for threads to finish
t1.Join();
t2.Join();

// At this point, all threads are done.
```

Of course, if this is an interactive application you'd want that to happen in a thread itself.  And if you wanted to get fancy, the waiting thread could do the work of one of the threads (i.e. you'd start thread 1 and then the main thread would do the work of the second thread).

If this is an interactive application, then you probably want to make use of `BackgroundWorker` (which used the thread pool).  If you attach an event handler to the `RunWorkCompleted` event, then you will be notified when the worker has completed its task.  If you have multiple workers, have a single `RunWorkCompleted` event handler, and keep track of which workers have signaled.  When they've all signaled, then your program can go ahead and do whatever else it needs to do.

The example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx should give you a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check the isAlive() value for each thread? if all values equal false then you would know that all your threads have ended.  Additionally, there is a way to have your delegate return it's own status.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isalive(v=VS.90).aspx